# Upgrading skimage version on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, scikit-image, raspberry-pi2

I've installed python packages using the synaptic package manager on Raspberry Pi-2. However, the skimage module version 0.6 is the latest available version in synaptic. Can someone guide me how to upgrade it to 0.11, as certain functions are missing in the older version.

I tried `pip install scikit-image`, but it gives the output

```
Running setup.py install for scikit image
```

and then gets stuck there.

Comment: What about downloading `scikit-image` and following the installation instructions?

Comment: I tried that too, downloaded the tarball and ran pip install . Again, the same getting stuck at running setup.py and filling up memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong there. It's just that there is a number of C extensions to compile in `scikit-image` and it is slow on Raspberry Pi.

For instance, on my laptop with i7 dual core CPU and an SSD, it takes around 5 minutes to install `scikit-image` from sources. Now if you take into account that the CPU on the RP2 is at least one order of magnitude slower, coupled with a slow SD card, it could take several hours to compile on a RP2.

You can see if you can run the compilations in parallel to speed things up, although I'm not sure if this is doable with `pip` and C extensions for a python module.