# raspberry pi 2- not able to install scikit-image

Tags: python, scipy, raspberry-pi2, scikit-image

yup i checked this too :- [Upgrading skimage version on Raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950941/upgrading-skimage-version-on-raspberry-pi)

but after running : pip install scikit-image

> ```
> Collecting scikit-image   Using cached scikit-image-0.12.3.tar.gz
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
> warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
> warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
> warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Utility'
> gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
> Please submit a full bug report,
> with preprocessed source if appropriate.
> See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
> Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/tmp/pip-build-YRFTcZ/scikit-image/setup.py", line 146, in <module>
>     **extra
>   File "/home/pi/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py",
> line 126, in setup
>     dist = setup(**new_attr)
>   File "/home/pi/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py",
> line 169, in setup
>     return old_setup(**new_attr)
>   File "/home/pi/miniconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
>     _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
>   File "/home/pi/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/numpy_distribution.py",
> line 16, in __init__
>     Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)
>   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 268, in __init__
>   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
>   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 836, in resolve
>   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1081, in best_match
>   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1093, in obtain
>   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
>   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
> line 638, in easy_install
>   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
> line 668, in install_item
>   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
> line 851, in install_eggs
>   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
>  line 1079, in build_and_install
>   File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
>  line 1067, in run_setup
>  distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command      'gcc' failed with exit status 4
>
> ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> /tmp/pip-build-YRFTcZ/scikit-image/
> ```

i have installed miniconda and using that also i'm unable to install

> ```
> conda install scikit-image
> ```

Comment: Since GCC failed, is must me some missing dependencies. Check on the docs for all the dependencies

Comment: thank you , i think the thing was matplotlib wasn't installed

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to first install matplotlib but if you simply do

> pip install matplotlib

You will get memError, so use the following:-

> $ pip --no-cache-dir install matplotlib

and after this install scikit-image using

> $ pip --no-cache-dir install scikit-image

note : this step can take an hour to complete

GL with your project !

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this without `matplotlib` you will get a screen of nasty messages on the raspberry Pi 2 when you try to install `scipy` image. I did this as part of what I was working on below and that works also. This is my first post I don't know how to format the posts it comes out in a line separate between pip's.

```
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
pip --no-cache-dir install matplotlib
pip -U install scikit-image
```